# ESRI JS API PopupMobile - view attribute page directly

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, mobile, popup, fields-attributes

I am using the ESRI Javascript API to write a mobile web application.  I have used the `PopupMobile` widget for viewing/editing attributes.  This widget creates a popup on the map when a feature(s) is clicked and then provides a button to access the attributes in a new page.

I would like to bypass the popup altogether and go directly to the attribute page.  Is this possible?

**UPDATE:**

I created my own `onClick` handler instead of using the `PopupMobile` widget, but I'm getting some very interesting results in my attributes page.

Here is a screenshot of the `AttributeInspector` widget as it displays on the page I set up in my application:

[image]

As you can see, the various `dijits` that make up the `AttributeInspector` are not displaying properly on the page.

Here is the code I used to set up the `AttributeInspector`:

```
mapDeferred.addCallback(function(response) {
    map = response.map;

    currentItem = response.itemInfo;
    $("#webmapTitle").html(currentItem.item.title);

    resizeMap();

    var fl = currentItem.itemData.operationalLayers[3].layerObject

    var layerInfo = [{
        featureLayer : fl
    }];

    var attInspector = new AttributeInspector({
        layerInfos : layerInfo
    }, "attributeInspector");
    attInspector.startup();

    dojo.connect(map, "onClick", function(evt) {

        var toleranceInPixels = 10;
        var pnt = evt.mapPoint;

        var pixelWidth = map.extent.getWidth() / map.width;
        var toleranceInMapCoords = toleranceInPixels * pixelWidth;
        var ext = new esri.geometry.Extent(pnt.x - toleranceInMapCoords,
            pnt.y - toleranceInMapCoords,
            pnt.x + toleranceInMapCoords,
            pnt.y + toleranceInMapCoords,
            map.spatialReference);

        var q = new esri.tasks.Query();
        q.geometry = ext;

        fl.selectFeatures(q)

        $.mobile.changePage($("#attributePage"));



    })
});
```

And here is the markup:

```
<!--Attribute Page-->
<div id="attributePage" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1><span>Attributes</span></h1>
        <a href="#mapPage" id="mapPageBtn5" data-rel="page" data-theme='b'
        class="ui-btn-right">Map</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="attributeInspector"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How are you going to tell the attribute page what record to edit? That is going to be the first part you need to consider. You can create your own on-click method when you select a object to trigger the edit function versus the infowindow.

Comment: @D.E.Wright - The user will still click on a feature as if they were opening the popup window, but instead of the popup opening on the map, it should go straight to the editing page.  I tried to write my own `onClick` handler to do this, but the Attribute Inspector widget does not appear correctly in the new page.